# Programming Resources for Non-English Speakers

Tags: html, css

I teach a course in basic web programming at a public university. I often have students who are working hard to pick up English at the same time that they are taking my course. In many cases I have thought that I would like to have additional course materials in a variety of languages to keep some of the technical hurdles from being compounded with linguistic ones.

Can anyone recommend a "stackoverflow" whose primary language base is Japanese, Chinese, Polish, or Spanish? Or similarly, a site in any of the listed languages that targets web development?

Edit: One thing I ask is that recommendations be based on use of the site and so familiarity with the language or reasonable knowledge of the sites reputation.

As one responder mentioned, students can google whatever question they have in their native language. While this can be a great tactic it doesn't always point to quality information.

Thanks!

Comment: The students I'm describing will not necessarily go into IT as I'm teaching the course within a humanities department. I'm not sure how the politics of China relate to my question.

Comment: There are currently a plenty of StackOverflow in (German, Portugese, Russian etc.) proposals on area51: http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=progress. Unfortunately StackOverflow code is not ready for internationalization yet, so noone knows how long will it take before those proposals start.

Comment: This would be on-topic at https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/ (though since it's still in private beta, it's easiest to enter through here https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92460/computer-science-educators)

Comment: asked in '09 ;-)

Answer (score 5):

http://cnprog.com/ is a site you might want to check out. It's a Chinese clone of StackOverflow.

Edit: I found some more. http://www.askdev.ru/ and http://throwcatch.me/ are Russian versions of StackOverflow. http://codekicker.de/ is in German and http://www.salonit.pl/ is Polish.

Comment: open source too! http://github.com/cnprog/CNPROG

Comment: cnprog.com and salonit.pl aren't available anymore. Codekicker is practically inactive - a few questions in month (at least for Java).

Answer (score 3):

It's not a generic Q&A site like Stack Overflow, but as a resource, the language's documentation has to count, right? [The PHP docs](http://php.net/docs.php) are available in English, Bulgarian, Portuguese, German, French, Japanese, Korean, Polish, Romanian and Turkish, plus they have [archives of other languages](http://au.php.net/manual/help-translate.php) which aren't listed as "active" any more, so they're probably well out-of-date but might still be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest that the students type their doubts, or keywords of subjects, into Google or other search engine, in their native languages.

That's how I find material in Portuguese at least. I'm Brazilian.

In the bigger language groups in the class, a few pioneers are bound to give the rest the links.

Comment: A good approach. Any sites in Portuguese you would recommend? I find that while google will give you many answers not all of them point to high quality information.

Comment: @moorej: sorry, no recommendations, because I have zero experience in web programming. My experience is that everything high-quality I find in the web is VERY specific, I don't know any good generic "programming" sites in Portuguese.

Answer (score 1):

[JavaHispano.org](http://www.javahispano.org/) for Spanish resources.

Comment: Thank you. Any focused on basic web development: HTML, CSS, Javascript, etc?